# Getting canonical name for each members of the users via powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to get canonical name for each groups as well. how can I do that ?

Here is my script :

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true}  -Properties * | Select displayname ,@{Name="MemberOf";Expression={($_.MemberOf | %{(Get-ADGroup $_).sAMAccountName}) -Join ";"}} | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

My output :

```
"displayname","MemberOf"
"User01","Group01;Group02;Group03"
```

My desired output:

```
"displayname","MemberOf"
"User01","Group01;Contoso.com/OU1/OU2;Group02;Contoso.com/OU21/OU52;Group03;Contoso.com/OU1/OU21/OU22"
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the `distinguishedName` instead? Canonical names are ambiguous, DNs are not.

Comment: I'm sure. I want to get canonical name

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68115278/getting-canonical-name-for-each-members-of-the-users-via-powershell#comment120389136_68115278) but this is how you can do it using the code you already have. Definitely recommend you to only call the properties that you need to query.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Properties Displayname,MemberOf |
Select-Object Displayname,
@{
    Name="MemberOf"
    Expression={
        # ($_.MemberOf | ForEach-Object{
        #    (Get-ADGroup $_ -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName
        # }) -Join ";"
    
        # You can pipe $_.MemberOf to Get-ADGroup, since it's an array of 
        # distinguishedNames it should work fine
        ($_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName -Join ";"    
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

---

An alternative to that code, using a more classical approach:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Properties DisplayName

$result = foreach($user in $users)
{
    $params = @{
        LDAPFilter = "(member=$($user.DistinguishedName))"
        Properties = "CanonicalName"
    }
    $membership = (Get-ADGroup @params).CanonicalName -join ";"

    [pscustomobject]@{
        DisplayName = $user.DisplayName
        MemberOf = $membership
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: its not working. returning null member of column

Comment: @Arbelac my bad, I missed removing the `$_` after `Get-ADGroup`. Try now.

Comment: now,  I am getting below output for alternative script.

Comment: "IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized","Keys","Values","SyncRoot","Count"
"False","False","False","System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection","System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection","System.Object","2"

Comment: @Arbelac not sure, this works fine for me, both examples.

Comment: ok now it works but I want to get an output like below.

Comment: "displayname","MemberOf"
"User01","Group01;Contoso.com/OU1/OU2;Group02;Contoso.com/OU21/OU52;Group03;Contoso.com/OU1/OU21/OU22"

Comment: So, I will see group names too

Comment: @Arbelac are you sure this line is exactly as in the code right? `$membership = (Get-ADGroup @params).CanonicalName -join ";"`. That should only be outputting the canonicalNames joined by `;`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be using `Properties *` when you only need two properties.
Then, the `-Filter` should be a **string**, not a scriptblock.

With just a small adaptation to your code, this should work:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -Properties DisplayName, MemberOf | 
Select-Object DisplayName,
    @{Name = "MemberOf"; Expression = {
        ($_.MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
            ($_ | Get-ADGroup -Properties CanonicalName).CanonicalName -Join ";" })
        }
    } | 
Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

---

Looking at your latest comment, I believe you want the group NAME joined with the canonicalname of the group as well.
You can do this like so:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -Properties DisplayName, MemberOf | 
Select-Object DisplayName,
    @{Name = "MemberOf"; Expression = {
        $_.MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
            $group = $_ | Get-ADGroup -Properties CanonicalName
            '{0};{1}' -f $group.Name, ($group.CanonicalName -join ';')
            }
        }
    } | 
Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\users.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Hi , I have a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75054855/powershell-dynamic-html-table   are you able to assist?

Comment: @Arbelac Please see my answer there